# If $B$ is linearly independent and $B \subseteq S$, then there is a subset $B'$ of $S$ such that $B'$ is a basis for $S$ and $B \subseteq B'$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am quite confused on proving the following theorem.

*Let $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $B$ be a subset of $S$ such that $B$ is
linearly independent. Then there is a subset $B'$ of S such that $B \subseteq B'$
and $B'$ is a basis for $S$.*

In the proof, it tells us that it follows directly from the following two theorems:

**Theorem 1:** *Suppose that $S := span \{u_1,u_2, ... ,u_m\} \subseteq \mathbb R^n$. If
$\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_k\} \subseteq S$ is linearly independent then $k \le m$ and
$S = span\{v_1, v_2, ... , v_k, u_{i_1}, u_{i_2}, ..., u_{i_{m−k}}\}$, where $\{i_1, i_2, ..., i_{m−k}\}$ are distinct elements of {1, 2, . . . , m}.*

**Theorem 2:** *Let $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. Then $S$ has a basis.*

However, I've tried proving this myself several ways and I still cant figure out how these two theorems prove the original statement. I am completely lost with this, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: These two theorems imply that $B$ can be extended to a basis $B'$ of $S$, and that's what you need.

Comment: Actually you can find a vector $u_{i_1}$ such that $u_{i_1}\notin \mathrm{span}(B)$ and we get a new linearly independent set $B_1$, which is contained in $S$. Repeat the process until we finally get a basis of $S$.

Comment: How though? I only got that from Theorem 2, S must have a basis. Let's say that $\{u_1, u_2, ..., u^m\}$ is a basis for S.  Then since B is linearly independent, it can be extended to another spanning set B', but doesn't say whether B' is linearly independent or not.

Comment: You can first get a spanning list, and delete vectors in this list if they are in the span of others, and vectors in $B$ will not be deleted.

Comment: Sheldon Axler's book Linear Algebra Done Right may help you. It's in 2.31-2.33.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. Thanks very much.